# Primeng upload success message wrong

Tags: file, primeng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQYwp.png)

I use the file component of primeng.

When i upload one file , all the others file block popup upload success message.

How to seperate the upload message?

Please help , thx.

this is example form primeng official website

```
<p-fileUpload name="demo[]" url="./upload.php" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" 
    multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" maxFileSize="1000000">
   <ng-template pTemplate="content">
       <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
           <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
       </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: use *ngIf tag to separate these messages, for example, if first one is updated set one variable and use *ngIf that variable show first message.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale  i edit the question. i add the example code.I don't know  where should to put *ngIf...

Comment: i am not getting your question which message you are talking about the one in green or the blue growl message which are shown in primeng messages. earlier I thought you are talking about the green messages which are shown in your given image.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale I mean the green with check  message. i upload file in third block but every block show green upload success message . I only want to show in third block . The green message is primeng default return message . i don't know how to controll it.

Comment: can you add that HTML tag here? if not you can inspect them and add. it will be easier to get the index of your file selected and according to you can show that message.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale Sorry i can't show that html tag because that is made by prmeng. i found that this question is issued https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4572
Hope primeng fix it as quick as possible.
thank for your answer~

Comment: that's good. happy coding brother .